# How to fix `prepareForSegue()` override `UIViewAnimation`

Tags: swift, segue, uiviewanimation, uistoryboardsegue, uiviewanimationtransition

I have `MainViewController` which has stack view and its width is over screen's width. There is slide out menu at left side of `storyboard`. And there is Menu button on the screen which triggers an animation to changes `UIStackView`'s from -260 to 0. But when I click some button at slide out menu, `prepareForSegue()` overrides the animation and content changes immediately. How can fix that?

You can find a gif below.

Here is the codes:

```
 class MainViewController: UIViewController
{
    var container: ContainerViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var superView: UIStackView!

    @IBAction func menuButtonsChangeContent(sender: AnyObject) {
        switch(sender.tag){
        case 1:
            container?.changeContent("first")
        case 2:
            container?.changeContent("second")
        case 3:
            container?.changeContent("third")
        default:
            break
        }
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Container"{
            self.slideOutMenu("")
            container = segue.destinationViewController as? ContainerViewController
        }
    }

    @IBAction func slideOutMenu(sender: AnyObject) {

        if self.superView.frame.origin.x != -260 {

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: ({

                self.superView.frame = CGRect(x: -260, y: 20, width: self.superView.frame.width, height: self.superView.frame.height)

            }), completion: nil)
        }else{
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: ({
                self.superView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.superView.frame.width, height: self.superView.frame.height)

            }), completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//ContainerViewController.swift       
 class ContainerViewController: UIViewController 
 {
    var sourceVC: UIViewController?
    var destinationVC: UIViewController?
    var segueIdentifier: String?
    var counter = 0

    func changeContent(segueIdentifier: String)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier, sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: ({

            if self.sourceVC != nil {
                self.sourceVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                print("deleted")
            }

            self.destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController
            self.addChildViewController(self.destinationVC!)
            self.destinationVC?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            self.view.addSubview((self.destinationVC?.view)!)
            self.destinationVC?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            self.sourceVC = self.destinationVC
        }), completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And Storyboard:

[image]

GIF:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a `UIStackView` as super view in `MainViewController` but an issue about shadows came up and I changed `UIStackView` to `UIView`. Maybe it is weird but the problem is gone.

[image]